# (regarding Interceptors) Difference between spring @Controller and @RestController

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I know there is a question about Difference between spring `@Controller` and `@RestController`, also I know the difference about the two annotations.

My question is regarding interceptors only, is there any difference between the two annotations when we define interceptors.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TemplateMappingInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**", "/admin-functions**").excludePathPatterns("/login**");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@RestController is a newer annotation introduced to simplify building of rest controllers. It includes the @Controller and @ResponseBody annotations.

In a wide point of view, they both do the same thing in the end, one in a simpler way. Interceptors operate on a higher level and are independent of the inner workings of a rest controller, so nope, there is no difference.